# Installing RubyGems on a CentOs 5.5

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos5, rbenv, chiliproject

I'm fairly new to Linux and i'm trying to install Chiliproject on a CentOs 5.5.

When I try to install rubygems to install Rails, here is what I get:

> [root@ns381286 ~]# sudo rbenv install 1.9.3-p125
>
> Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
>
> Installing yaml-0.1.4...
>
> Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125
>
> Downloading http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz...
>
> Installing ruby-1.9.3-p125...
>
> Installed ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /root/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125
>
> [root@ns ~]# sudo rbenv rehash
>   [root@ns ~]# cd rubygems/
>
> [root@ns rubygems]# sudo ruby setup.rb
>
> /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 4: exec: rbenv: not found

Does anyone know what the error might be? I tried to reinstall but it didnt change anything.

Here is the tutorial I used: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was an issue on the server side. It's working nicely now.